# Isometric + oversimplified style scene and Rendering configuration

Tags: rendering, scene

Any advise on how to reach a similar effect in Blender (possibly without the use of any additional software / plugin)

Specifically, I'm curious about the camera view (it feels like some sort of isometric view), the light effect (it seems cartoonish, equally diffused, although there is some shadow casting) and the colour (materials and texture are very simple and vivid in colours)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure without having things in (screen space) horizontal + vertical of known equal size.  If the view is angled relative to the ground plane, this is simply a raised orthogonal view, pitched downwards:

[image]

Planes are equal width; you can see the view angle in the apparent thinness of the horizontal plane.

If this is instead a distorted top view, then this could probably be made by lattice deforming everything 3D:

[image]

It's a very simple lattice, where I've created a shapekey to just push some stuff back (in world +Y.)  Everything can use the exact same lattice.  Then when I view from an orthogonal top-down view, the lattice gives some pseudo-perspective.

Lighting is a sun light and some ambient (a flat colored world); materials are mostly just diffuse.  The plastic is a high roughness refract shader at IOR 1.0.)  The hemispheres in 11 may have some specular.